# Make entire top bar hover-able without use of image

Tags: html, css

So I have been using an image to make the area work, but I had been using a very wide image with a white background to just give the illusion of the area being hoverable.  However this causes issues on smaller screens as the image becomes tiny.

http://outside.hobhob.uk

The area I am referring to is the top white bar with the middle arrow.  I want to be able to remove the image (http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/img/a.jpg) and replace it with a simple text arrow;

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
```

So editing the following code;

```
 <header id="header" role="banner">

<center id="showHeader">
<img src="http://outside.hobhob.uk/test/img/a.jpg">
      <div class="headwidth">
            <h1 class="logo">
<a href="index.html" title="Outside The Line"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            </h1> 
          <nav id="main-nav">
        <a href="index.html">Work</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>

        </nav>  
        </div>
</center> 
    </header>
```

and the following CSS:

```
center#showHeader > img:hover + .headwidth, .headwidth:hover 
{
height: 220px;
width: 100%;
}
.headwidth {
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    transition: .7s;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
    color:#29251F;
    font-size: 84px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left;
}
.logo a {

margin:0 auto;
}
```

I had added :hover to the end of #showHeader but this just stops it working all together when I add the arrow text in to replace the image.. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: What can I use instead?  Any suggestions?

Comment: now it working right?

Comment: There are many centering solutions but that element has been removed from the HTML spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
center#showHeader:hover > .headwidth {
  height: 220px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

instead of using the icon for your action, use the bar itself. No aiming required.

Comment: Amazing!! This has done it, I did not even think to just remove stuff!  Genius!  Thank you so much!  The more I learn, the more I end up making my code more simple!  Huge help and a huge eye opener for me :) Thanks loads!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
center#showHeader:hover > img:hover + .headwidth, .headwidth:hover {...}
```

Try to use

```
center#showHeader:hover > .fa.fa-arrow-down:hover + .headwidth, .headwidth:hover {...}
```

Comment: Hey,

This works on getting the arrow to work with the hover, but now all the white space does not react, any ideas on how I can make the entire area react?

Thanks!

Comment: Give width: 100%; to arrow element(<i> tag)

Comment: How would I do this?
I tried adding;
<i width="100%" class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
 but it does not do anything to the surrounding area.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your image just use a div with the font-awesome in it

```css
.header-trigger {
  text-align: center;
  padding:1em 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header-trigger">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
</div>
```

The your trigger is

```
#showHeader > .header-trigger:hover + .headwidth, .headwidth:hover
```

Comment: Hey,
Thanks for the help.

I have changed these bits but seem to have lost the hover all together.. Should I be placing the whole header area within that div? Currently I have the Div code you provided, then its followed by the Headwidth Div etc

Comment: If the image is triggering the action then just substituting in the div *for* the image should work